# How to correctly specify variables in a function?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, function-construction

There is an expression

`(Sqrt[\[Pi]] (a b^2 d^3 + a (b^2 d^3 + 2 a (b + b d^3))) r[1, 1] r[1,  4])/(2 c^2 (b + b d^3)^(3/2)) - ( Sqrt[\[Pi]] (a b^2 d^4 + a (b^2 d^4 + 2 c (b d + b d^3))) r[5, 2] r[ 1, 4])/(2 a^2 (b d + b c^3)^(3/2))`

where `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `r[1, 1]`, `r[1, 4]`, `r[5, 2]` are variables.

I would like to write this expression as a function `f` where `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `r[1, 1]`, `r[1, 4]`, `r[5, 2]` are variables. It can be indicated that `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are variables as follows `f[a_,b_,c_,d_]:= the expression`, but how can I specify that `r[1, 1]`, `r[1, 4]` and `r[5, 2]` are also variables `f[a_,b_,c_,d_,...]:= the expression`?

Comment: Simplest: `f[a_,b_,c_,d_,r_]:=` the expression.

Comment: @Alan, the variables `r[1, 1]`, `r[1, 4]`, `r[5, 2]` and `r[1, 4]`  have different values

Comment: @Alan, for example `a=1`, `b=2`, `c=1`, `d=1` and `r[1, 1]=2`, `r[1, 4]=3`, `r[5, 2]=5`, `r[1, 4]=6`, that is, it can be specified in the function `f[1,2,1,1, but how to specify values for r[...,...]]`?

Comment: To be more specific, my `allowNonSymbol` therein is exactly for the task.

Comment: @xzczd, thanks a lot for the useful link!

Comment: You list `r[1, 4]` twice in each of the four variable lists; the last time, in a comment, you give it two different values. Why? How can the same expression have two different values simulataneously? Is it a mistake?

Comment: @Michael E2,  yes, thanks for pointing out the typo

Comment: With @Alan's suggestion, call `f` thus: `f[1,2,1,1, <|1 -> <|1 -> 2, 4 -> 3 (* or 6 *)|>, 5 -> <|2 -> 5|>|>]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure I'm misunderstanding something, so this isn't so much an answer as an attempt to force more clarity.

Here is a function:

```
theFunction[arg1_, arg2_, arg3_, arg4_, arg5_, arg6_, arg7_] := 
  ((arg1*arg2^2*arg4^3 + arg1*(arg2^2*arg4^3 + 2*arg1*(arg2 + arg2*arg4^3)))*arg5*arg6*Sqrt[Pi])/
   (2*arg3^2*(arg2 + arg2*arg4^3)^(3/2)) - 
  ((arg1*arg2^2*arg4^4 + arg1*(arg2^2*arg4^4 + 2*arg3*(arg2*arg4 + arg2*arg4^3)))*arg6*arg7*Sqrt[Pi])/
   (2*arg1^2*(arg2*arg3^3 + arg2*arg4)^(3/2))
```

Applying the function as follows will reproduce your original expression:

```
theFunction[a, b, c, d, r[1, 1], r[1, 4], r[5, 2]]
```

And so, in the specific example you gave in one of your comments:

```
theFunction[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
(* -9*Sqrt[Pi] *)
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: It's not, I'm afraid. See the suggested duplicate above.

Comment: @lericr, thanks for this answer! I'll try to use it (simply redefine all variables of this type `r[..., ...]` to regular string variables.

Comment: @MamMam - `expr = <your expression>; param = {a, b, c, d, r[1, 1], r[1, 4], r[5, 2]}; f = Function @@ ({param, expr} /. {r[1, 1] -> r11, r[1, 4] -> r14, r[5, 2] -> r52})`

Answer (score 2):

Using `r` essentially as a private keyword is dangerous, if `r` is not protected. For instance, setting `r = 7` will generally mess up any code that assumes `r` is an undefined symbol. You can `Protect` it, which will protect your code from most bugs, but `Protect` can be overridden. (There is also `Locked`, if you want, then the following won't work.)

That aside, assuming `r` is safe but not protected:

```
ClearAll[f];
f[a_, b_, c_, d_, r11_, r14_, r52_] := Block[{r},
   (*Unprotect[r];*)  (* uncomment if r is protected *)
   r[1, 1] = r11; r[1, 4] = r14; r[5, 2] = r52;
   (*Protect[r];*)    (* uncomment if r is protected *)
   (* OP's expression *)
   (Sqrt[\[Pi]] (a b^2 d^3 + a (b^2 d^3 + 2 a (b + b d^3))) r[1, 1] r[
        1, 4])/(2 c^2 (b + b d^3)^(3/2)) - (Sqrt[\[Pi]] (a b^2 d^4 + 
         a (b^2 d^4 + 2 c (b d + b d^3))) r[5, 2] r[1, 
        4])/(2 a^2 (b d + b c^3)^(3/2))
   ];

f[1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5]
(*  -9 Sqrt[\[Pi]]  *)
```

Again, I will point out that we're assuming it is safe to treat `` Global`r `` as a reserved keyword. If this is combined with other code that uses `r` in a different way, you may find you have bugs. I offer this answer in the spirit of showing the difficulties of using a tool (Mma) in ways it wasn't really designed for.  It would be better practice to rewrite your `r` variables as `r11`, `r14`, `r52`, which is essentially what @lericr's answer recommends.

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Yes, I agree with that this is a good way to redefine variables

Comment: @MamMam One could use `Module` instead of `Block` and then `r` is properly localized.  I was originally thinking that the expression was pre-defined and `r` had to be global. But looking at how it is coded above, the expression is, and needs to be, explicitly in the body of the function. I should have used `Module` in hindsight.

Comment: Thanks for the comment!